# python negative sum of rows on matrix diagonal efficiently

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, diagonal

I need to sum the rows of a matrix, negate them, and put them on the diagonal of either the original matrix or a matrix where the off-diagonal terms are zero. What works is

```
 Mat2 = numpy.diag(numpy.negative(numpy.squeeze(numpy.asarray(numpy.sum(Mat1,axis=1))))
```

Is there a cleaner/faster way to do this? I'm trying to optimize some code.

Comment: Do you really need the `numpy.asarray`? -- It won't do much for your runtime, but the code might look a little more tractable without it.  Also, `numpy.negative(...)` can be more succinctly written as `-...`.  Again, no runtime benefits, but slightly shorter code.

Comment: I was having a problem where the sum output something with an extra pair of brackets and then numpy.diag() output a matrix containing a single element. I'm not too worried about speed up (for this particular piece), but what I have right now is really ugly looking for what seems to be a simple problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `np.diag(-Mat1.A.sum(1))` would produce the same results:

```
>>> Mat1 = np.matrix(np.random.rand(3,3))
>>> Mat1
matrix([[ 0.35702661,  0.0191392 ,  0.34793743],
        [ 0.9052968 ,  0.16182118,  0.2239716 ],
        [ 0.57865916,  0.77934846,  0.60984091]])
>>> Mat2 = np.diag(np.negative(np.squeeze(np.asarray(np.sum(Mat1,axis=1)))))
>>> Mat2
array([[-0.72410324,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        , -1.29108958,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        , -1.96784852]])
>>> np.diag(-Mat1.A.sum(1))
array([[-0.72410324,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        , -1.29108958,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        , -1.96784852]])
```

Note that matrices are a bit of a headache in numpy -- arrays are generally much more convenient -- and the only syntactic advantage they had, namely easier multiplication, doesn't really count any more now that we have `@` for matrix multiplication in modern Python.

If `Mat1` were an array instead of a matrix, you wouldn't need the `.A` there.

Comment: This is beautiful. Thank you so much!